# How to proceed with the JWT token on client side, after middleware

Tags: express, authentication, flask, jwt, flask-jwt-extended

i want to Authenticate my routes with JWT and i have some questions. I have a flask backend server and i am using the `jwt extended flask` library. When i log in to my app i produce a JWT token with this way

```
app.config["JWT_COOKIE_SECURE"] = False #This is False on locahost
app.config["JWT_TOKEN_LOCATION"] = ["cookies"]
app.config['JWT_CSRF_IN_COOKIES'] = True
..........
access_token = create_access_token(identity= token)
response_data = jsonify({
   'success': True,
   'message': 'You have successfully logged in',
})
set_access_cookies(response_data, access_token)
```

I sent the token to middleware with the above way, as a `http-only cookie`.

My middleware is on `express js` and i manipulate the `JWT token` there:
I access the token and the csrf like this:

```
const setCookieHeader = response.headers['set-cookie']
const access_token_cookie = setCookieHeader[0]
.......
const csrf_access_token = setCookieHeader[1]

var decodes_jwt = jwt.verify(token, config.jwtSecret)
```

And i save the csrf to a cookie. My question is that i suppose to do? I decode the `JWT` inside the middleware like i do now, and how the client get it to sent it to other requests i want to make. Also i see that some they sent only the `csrf_access_token` and authenticate with this only without the `JWT` ?? I don't know if this is valid too.

My code that i am using in my middleware for requests is like this:

```
const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  withCredentials: true,
})
axiosInstance.post(`${clientUrls.cloudapi}/get_my_route`,
{
},
{ headers: {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  // 'Authorization': `Bearer ${req.get('Authorization').split('bearer ')[1]}`,
  // Authorization: `Bearer ${req.cookies['csrf']}`
  'X-CSRF-TOKEN': req.cookies['csrf'],
 }
 }).then((response) => {
```

In my backend to authenticate the JWT i am doing this

```
@app.route("/get_my_route", methods=["POST"])
@jwt_required()
def _getRoute():
  current_user = get_jwt_identity() 
  ........
```

With the above implementation i get `401 Unauthorized`

So my basic question is how to manage the `JWT` in the client side(I am writting `reactJS`), so to sent it through the the server to validate the request.